# Stored procedure does not update list data when called second time in a run

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

I am using Entity Framework in a Blazor app to populate a data grid using a stored procedure. The procedure is called on page initialization and on a ValueChange event.

This is my function:

```cs
public async Task<List<Tabel>> GetData(DateTime dataRef)
{
    string dataUWU = dataRef.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    List<TabelRaportari>? data = null;
    _dbContext.TabelRaportaris.Local.Clear();
    
    data = await _dbContext.TabelRaportaris
                               .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC RASF {dataUWU}, null")
                               .ToListAsync();
    return data;
}
```

This is my model:

```cs
public class TabelRaportari
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public string? limit {  get; set; }
    public string? obs {  get; set; }
    public DateTime? dataScadenta { get; set; }
}
```

It runs perfectly the first time, no matter what DateTime I use to run it, but when I change the date, the date comes through to the stored the procedure, the result comes back as expected, except for a DateTime column, where the date is recalculated by the stored procedure.

So the list updates, but the data is not recalculated.

I'm using the stored procedure in a similar app that still uses .Net framework and it works just fine.

Comment: 1. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor on how to use Unit of work DBContexts in Blazor

Comment: 2. So on `return data` what are you seeing.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand the unit of work part. I created a dbContextFactory and it works properly now.  Thanks @MrCakaShaunCurtis!

Comment: NP.  I added that comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/… on how to use Unit of work DBContexts in Blazor